# Is there a fast way to list the threads in the current Windows process?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

I'm writing a tool that needs to walk all the threads of the current process regularly under Windows. So far, so good.

So I'm using [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot), then walking the thread list. Unfortunately, my profiler shows that this is very expensive (~30% CPU when I repeat this about once per second).

Is there a better/faster way to do this?

Comment: You could have a look at https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker it's a bit like a goldmine

Comment: An obvious optimization would be to replace `TH32CS_SNAPALL` with `TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD`.

Comment: For what information do you need to walk the current process threads?

Comment: If you have a dll in your process that you control, its main entry point gets called whenever a new thread is starting or when one exits. You could use that to maintain a list of active threads.

Comment: `ZwQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemProcessInformation` is fastest way.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - yes, possible. but in this case better use tls-callback in exe, and not need dll

Comment: @RbMm: Define `better`. Personally, I like to use methods that are officially documented and supported.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError use tls callbacks is better in sense that not need separate dll in process. and tls also documented and suported

Comment: `NtGetNextThread` enumerates threads in a process, but it's undocumented. Start with `hThread = NULL`. In a loop: `status = NtGetNextThread(GetCurrentProcess(), hThread, THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, 0, 0, &hThreadNext)` and `CloseHandle(hThread)`. If `status == 0` (success), assign `hThread = hThreadNext` and query required information such as `GetThreadId(hThread)` and `GetThreadPriory(hThread)`. The enumeration ends with `status == STATUS_NO_MORE_ENTRIES` (0x8000001A).

Comment: After the process is created, you could also use WMI to receive notifications of thread creation instead of polling: [Example: Receiving Event Notifications Through WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--receiving-event-notifications-through-wmi-).

Comment: @IInspectable My bad, it was `TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD`. Fixing question.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov I'm writing a task manager. I need the thread names.

Comment: @ErykSun Thanks! This should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before Windows 8.1, you can use `NtGetNextThread` as @ErykSun mentioned in the question comments, but it's not documented.

Since Windows 8.1, you can use `PssCaptureSnapshot`. Example usage can be found [here](https://github.com/zodiacon/Win10SysProgBookSamples/blob/master/Chapter20/snapproc/snapproc.cpp).

Both solutions query only the desired process and not the whole system, so they're much faster.

The relevant parts, just in case:

```cpp
#include <processsnapshot.h>

// ...

HPSS hSnapshot;
error = ::PssCaptureSnapshot(hProcess, PSS_CAPTURE_THREADS, 0, &hSnapshot);

// ...

PSS_THREAD_INFORMATION info;
if(ERROR_SUCCESS != ::PssQuerySnapshot(hSnapshot, PSS_QUERY_THREAD_INFORMATION, &info, sizeof(info))) {
    printf("No thread information\n");
    return;
}

printf("Threads captured: %u\n", info.ThreadsCaptured);

HPSSWALK hWalk;
if(ERROR_SUCCESS == ::PssWalkMarkerCreate(nullptr, &hWalk)) {
    PSS_THREAD_ENTRY thread;
    while(ERROR_SUCCESS == ::PssWalkSnapshot(hSnapshot, PSS_WALK_THREADS, hWalk, &thread, sizeof(thread))) {
        printf("TID: %6u Created: %s Priority: %2d User: %s Kernel: %s\n",
            thread.ThreadId,
            TimeToString(thread.CreateTime).c_str(),
            thread.Priority,
            TimeSpanToString(thread.UserTime).c_str(), TimeSpanToString(thread.KernelTime).c_str());
    }
    ::PssWalkMarkerFree(hWalk);
}

// ...

::PssFreeSnapshot(::GetCurrentProcess(), hSnapshot);
```